# How to fix the position of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef84qxyL/4/) And this is my code:

```css
.recommendedmovies {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.moviescard {
    width:185px;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline-block;
 height:450px;
 vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}

.movierating {
}
```

```html
<div class="recommendedmovies">
    <ol>
        <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/imekS7f1OuHyUP2LAiTEM0zBzUz.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
            <p class="moviename">Wonder Woman</p>
            <p class="movierating">8/10</p> 
        </li>
        <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/xbpSDU3p7YUGlu9Mr6Egg2Vweto.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
            <p class="moviename">Pirates of the Caribbean: Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales </p>
            <p class="movierating">6/10</p> 
        </li>
        <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/2n4x2FRcmMIsHxcucxvWxb0Yry6.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
            <p class="moviename">War for the Planet of the Apes</p>
            <p class="movierating">5/10</p> 
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I want to make the rating's below the movie name, stay in a single line, like shown in the screenshot (on imaginary red line).

Let me know, if you need more information, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please activate Windows before doing anything else.

Comment: It's legal @Justinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.moviescard` position to relative (the context), and position the `.movierating` absolutely to the bottom of the card.

```css
.recommendedmovies {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.moviescard {
  position: relative;
  width: 185px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 450px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}

.movierating {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommendedmovies">
  <ol>
    <li class="moviescard">
      <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/imekS7f1OuHyUP2LAiTEM0zBzUz.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
      <p class="moviename">Wonder Woman</p>
      <p class="movierating">8/10</p>
    </li>


    <li class="moviescard">
      <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/xbpSDU3p7YUGlu9Mr6Egg2Vweto.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
      <p class="moviename">Pirates of the Caribbean: Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales </p>
      <p class="movierating">6/10</p>
    </li>


    <li class="moviescard">
      <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/2n4x2FRcmMIsHxcucxvWxb0Yry6.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
      <p class="moviename">War for the Planet of the Apes</p>
      <p class="movierating">5/10</p>
    </li>



  </ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your movie card and and image have fix dimension .. so just add

```
.moviename{
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: UV - The simple solution is always the best :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:relative` in `li` and `position:absolute` in `.movierating` class

```css
.recommendedmovies {
 overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
}


.moviescard {
  width:185px;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline-block;
 height:450px;
 vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    position: relative;
}

.movierating {
  bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommendedmovies">
      <ol>
          <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/imekS7f1OuHyUP2LAiTEM0zBzUz.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
           <p class="moviename">Wonder Woman</p>
           <p class="movierating">8/10</p> 
         </li>
         
         
          <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/xbpSDU3p7YUGlu9Mr6Egg2Vweto.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
           <p class="moviename">Pirates of the Caribbean: Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales </p>
           <p class="movierating">6/10</p> 
         </li>
         
         
          <li class="moviescard">
            <img class="lazy" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/2n4x2FRcmMIsHxcucxvWxb0Yry6.jpg" width="217px" height="325px" />
           <p class="moviename">War for the Planet of the Apes</p>
           <p class="movierating">5/10</p> 
         </li>
        
        
        
         </ol>
 
     </div>
```